# Dojox Mobile - Submit form via ToolBarButton callback?

Tags: javascript, forms, mobile, callback, dojo

Using a Dojox Mobile ToolBarButton (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton.html), how can I submit a form with ID "myformID" when the button is pressed?

The ToolBarButton accepts a "callback" parameter which I'm pretty sure is the one to use, but I can't get it to do even a simple JS alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to solve the same problem. This worked for me:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton" data-dojo-props="onClick: function() {document.getElementById('myformID').submit();}">Log in</button>
```